# AsyncDisplayKit AsViewController and swift 3

Tags: ios, asyncdisplaykit

trying to use AsyncdisplayKit for the 1st time in swift 3.

There is something that i do not understand :

i simply set up my ASviewController :

```
   final class NodeFeedViewController: ASViewController<ASDisplayNode>, ASTableDataSource, ASTableDelegate {

var tableNode: ASTableNode {
    return node as! ASTableNode
}

init() {
    super.init(node: ASTableNode())
    self.node.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    self.node.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    self.tableNode.delegate = self
    self.tableNode.dataSource = self
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("storyboards are incompatible with truth and beauty")
}
```

Then i set up my ASTableNode :

```
func tableNode(tableNode: ASTableNode, nodeForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ASCellNode {

    let rowCount = 15

    let node = ASTextCellNode()
    node.text = String(format: "[%ld.%ld] says hello!", indexPath.section, indexPath.row)

    return node
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableNode(tableNode: ASTableNode) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableNode(tableNode: ASTableNode, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count = 16
    return count
}
```

Problem is that i compile because Xcode tells me that my controller does not conform to protocol 'ASCommon TableViewDataSource', the only way to make it work is to add the native :

```
/*
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}*
```

/

Any idea why it is not working on my project and that it's work on the swift example projet of AsyncdisplayKit ? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Need to conform protocol. Add this `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: yea but on the example swift projet, it's working. I would like to know why. Furthermore there is func tableNode(tableNode: ASTableNode, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { so i should not need this no ?

Comment: maybe it configured on storyboard.

Comment: ? what do u mean. We cannot use storyboard with asyncdisplaykit, i add my asviewcontroller as a child of my view controller

Comment: Can you link to the swift project to which you refer please?

Comment: No i can"t sorry, company's project, this has been resolved using a simple trick, let Xcode autocomplete and do it again then remove the 1st one

Answer (score 0):

First: you need put your `ViewController()` in `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    window.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController());
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    self.window = window
    return true
}
```

***ViewController()** is the name of your controller that contains the table.

Second: check if your MainStoryboard don't have the viewcontroller associated, if it is, only clear that field.

Third: Don't forget to install the pod in your project.